# React-Native iOS reference xcassets image gets wrong size

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**Xcode 10.0**

**iOS 7 and up**

I have an app set up so that it loads with a particular launch image handled by the `xcassets`, with the proper sizes for **iOS 6** and up. These images load fine.

When the app finishes loading, I want to use the load image as the background of the in-app `splash/login button`. I use an Image (or BackgroundImage) with `source={{uri: "LaunchImage"}}` and the `xcassets` have the proper sizes and naming conventions *(Default.png, Default@2x.png, Default-568@2x.png, etc)*.

In the app, however, it seems to only reference the base, smallest image *(Default.png)* instead of the one properly sized *(eg, Default-568@2x.png for 7)*.

Is this something React-Native should be handling properly? Is there a way for me to specify which size in the source.uri?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can `scale` property to fit the image inside `Image` component if it is looking smaller.

```
icon={{uri: check', scale: 2}}
```

We don't need to worry about taking care about fit the image with different sizes for different devices.

According to React Native doc.s

The file structure:

```
├── button.js
└── img
    ├── check@2x.png
    └── check@3x.png
```

Your .js file:

```
<Image source={require('./img/check.png')} />
```

> The node packager will bundle and serve the image corresponding to
>   device's screen density. For example, `check@2x.png`, will be used on
>   an `iPhone 7`, while `check@3x.png` will be used on an `iPhone 7 Plus`
>   or a `Nexus 5`. If there is no image matching the screen density, the
>   closest best option will be selected.